# Why is Entity Framework not returning proper values for Id columns but correct values for everything else?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an Entity Framework table called `Customer`. It has a FK to another table called `BillLocation`. That table contains many addresses. The address table has a FK of `BillLocation` there.

Now my Entity Framework code works as intended and all the data is accurate however, when I go to retrieve that data any PK id is 0 even though in the database it is not. There are no errors or exceptions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my database call:
/*updated*/

```
public List<DataModel.Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            List<DataModel.Customer> customers = (from s in context.Customer
                     join cc in context.CustomerBillLocation on s.CustomerBillLocationId equals cc.CustomerBillLocationId
                     join cs in context.CustomerShipLocation on s.CustomerShipLocationId equals cs.CustomerShipLocationId
                     from od in context.Address
                     .Where(w=>w.CustomerShipLocationId == cs.CustomerShipLocationId || w.CustomerBillLocationId == cc.CustomerBillLocationId).DefaultIfEmpty() 

                     select s ).ToList();
            var address = (from s in context.Address select s).ToList();

            foreach(DataModel.Customer c in customers)
            {
               foreach (DataModel.Address a in c.CustomerBillLocation.Addresses)
                {
                    a.AddressId = address.FirstOrDefault(o => o.CustomerShipLocationId ==null && o.IsDefault).AddressId;
                }
               foreach(DataModel.Address a in c.CustomerShipLocation.Addresses)
                {
                    a.AddressId = address.FirstOrDefault(o => o.CustomerBillLocationId == null && a.Address1 == o.Address1).AddressId;
                }

            }

            return customers;
        }
    }
```

Here is my class definition
/*Updated*/

```
 public class Customer
    {
    [Key]
            public int CustomerId { get; set; }
            public int? CustomerBillLocationId { get; set; }
            public int? CustomerShipLocationId { get; set; }
            public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
            public string CustomerName { get; set; }
            public PaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
            public Region Region { get; set; }
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("CustomerBillLocationId")]
            public virtual CustomerBillLocation CustomerBillLocation { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("CustomerShipLocationId")]
            public virtual CustomerShipLocation CustomerShipLocation { get; set; }
    }
    /*Updated*/
public class CustomerBillLocation
{
   [Key]
    public int CustomerBillLocationId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
  /*Updated*/  
public class Address
{
     [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerBillLocationId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerShipLocationId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerBillLocationId")]
    public virtual CustomerBillLocation CustomerBillLocation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerShipLocationId")]
    public virtual CustomerShipLocation CustomerShipLocation { get; set; }    }
```

Here is my context file

```
public MyContext()
            : base("MyContext")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CustomerBillLocation> CustomerBillLocation { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CustomerShipLocation> CustomerShipLocation { get; set; }
```

My question is why are all pkid's coming back as 0 and how do I correct this. If you need more detail please let me know.

I have attached a screenshot while debugging:

[image]

EDIT: I have updated the code to reflect additional information. In addition I now have the results I want to return. The problem is that its a hack. I still can not use my virtual properties as they have the pkid as 0 so the only way is to get the table by itself and then iterate through customer and assign the correct pkids. Also to help give more background. On the web application I have a button which says give me all customers. I click it and the code makes its way to the database. Then I want it to return with data. Which it does infact return with the correct data. Except for the PKID which is 0 and not the correct value.

Edit2: I seed my database by using the configuration file and I just call a new customer so the constructor for customer looks like this

```
public Customer()
        {
            AccountNumber = "1345346456444398";
            CustomerName = "Wayne Enterprises";
            CustomerBillLocation = new DataModel.CustomerBillLocation();
            CustomerShipLocation = new DataModel.CustomerShipLocation();
            PaymentType = new PaymentType("Test");
            Region = new Region("East");
            UserId = 1;
        }
```

my contstructor for customerbilllocation looks like this

```
public CustomerBillLocation()
        {
            Addresses = new List<Address>
            {
                new Address()
            };
        }
```

and my address constructor looks like this

```
 public Address()
        {
            Address1 = "Wayne Manor Dr.";
            City = "Gotham";
            State = new State("MA");
            Zip = "55555";
            IsDefault = true;

        }
```

Comment: How are you mapping the properties?

Comment: @mxmissile I am not quite sure I understand your question. Which might be what I am missing. I will update my question with my context.cs

Comment: I also have an override for OnModelCreating where I have a line like this for each table. modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().ToTable("Address");

By mapping I am using the annotations or the virtual Customer. I thought EF took care of the rest, unless I have to explicitly state what the mapping should be?

Comment: Ok, the question is about PKs, but you didn't show the PK properties and their configuration (if any).

Comment: @IvanStoev I've Added more of my class definition to my post. I do have PK created. I made the assumption that EF would see the class name plus ID and create the pk for me. I'm guessing I need to make it explicit?

Comment: You should make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  As this question is, you've shown us small snippets of your code, but not enough to give us a clear idea of what's happening.  Posting a smaller, but complete project that has the same issue would help us out.

Comment: @jtslugmaster08 Yes, from what you have shown, everything seem to be following the EF conventions, hence no additional configuration is needed. Now, as you can imagine, this is not a normal EF behavior, so we really need a repro ([mcve]) as per *Sam I am* comment.

Comment: Not sure if you can use a relational navigation property and a FK id property at the same time. Try ditching one or the other.

Comment: @mxmissile I think you are on to something there if I do 

var x = (from address) I get the proper addressId 

however if I navigate through the relational navigation property the addressId in that property is 0;

Is there a better way to write my join statement?

my goal for the join statement is for a customer(which can have more than one address) I want to return every occurance of customer per unique address

Comment: Try adding a `[Key]` attribute to `AddressId`.

Comment: Can you give us the table definitions in the database, too?

Comment: @DanielLorenz Is there something specific you are looking for? They are the same as it is Code First.

Comment: I'm wondering how CustomerBillLocation goes to Address without having an AddressId as part of the data.

Comment: @DanielLorenz CustomerBillLocationID is in address the virtual property in ef knows about this relationship and adds every address to the virtual collection where the BillLocationId matches. Atleast that is my understanding of it. However when entityframework pulls the data back the pkid is set to 0. all other properties are correctly reflected.

Comment: Looking at the updated code, it seems like you are zeroing out the `AddressId` property by your `a.AddressId = address.FirstOrDefault(...` statements.

Comment: @IvanStoev Actually that is doing the opposite. Its setting it to the properId value because outside the foreach it is zero.

Comment: Mate, you seem to be putting too much "business" logic into your entity constructors, thus breaking the EF lazy loading. Don't initialize the reference navigation properties like `CustomerBillLocation` and `CustomerShipLocation`. Optionally initialize only the collection navigation properties to `new List<T>` or `new HastSet<T>`, and don't add values to them. Remember that the EF entity model is supposed to represent the store (i.e. database) state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to all who posted comments. And a special thanks to @IvanStoev. The solution as pointed out by Ivan was that I was initializing the virtual properties. By removing that, when I debugged and looked at what customer contained, it did indeed have the proper primary key values and proper data as well. Below is the corrected Constructors. The moral of the story was to not initialize virtual properties and to let Entity Framework do that for me.

```
    public RPGContext()
        : base("RPGContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }


public Customer()
        {
            AccountNumber = "1345346456444398";
            CustomerName = "Stark Industries";
            UserId = 1;
        }
public CustomerBillLocation()
        {
            Addresses = new List<Address>();
        }
public Address()
        {
            Address1 = "Wayne Manor Dr.";
            City = "Gotham";
            Zip = "55555";
            IsDefault = true;

        }
```